# Не допустимы / недопустимы

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

Можем ли мы с вами допустить раздельное написание?

Answer (score 1):

Недопустимо пишется слитно всегда.

Comment: >Наши дети: Подростки (2004) По всей видимости Вам в детстве внушали (не обязательно прямым текстом, а исподволь) **что это плохо и не допустимо**, так эта мысль и сидит у Вас в подсознании.

Answer (score 1):

http://slovari21.ru/community/1052

По-моему, сама по себе глагольная форма допустить в ЭТОМ значении не подразумевает активного производителя действия в Т. п. (пусть даже формально не выраженного)и не может быть причастием.

Форма допущен кем? возможна, а допустим кем? - звучит странно "Такой тон не допустим нами",как и "никем не допустим".Только недопустим где? Сама форма категорична, усиление с помощью отрицания будет избыточно, следовательно, это прилагательное со значением "возможный, позволительный".Слово недопустимый, недопустим можно заменить любым синонимичным прилагательным без не - например, плохой, ошибочный, преступный, аморальный и пр.

Значит, всегда пишется слитно.

Comment: Кажется, страдательное причастие настоящего времени образуется только от глаголов несовершенного вида?

Comment: Да, именно так. Значит, можем допустить раздельное написание только в сочетании с отрицательным наречием или сочетанием "ни в коей мере не"

Comment: Людмила, София, спасибо Вам за ответы.
Сомнения были в понимании к какой части речи следует относить "допустимы". Были предположения, что это краткое причастие. Но, как выяснилось ниже, причастия (страдательные) от глаголов с.в. на -мый  не образуются, и в моём случае это краткая форма отглагольного прилагательного.
"Для зданий, находящихся в аварийном состоянии, дополнительные перемещения недопустимы". Предполагается, что "недопустимы" нормативными документами, но звучит действительно странно. И краткая форма в данном случае образована, видимо, от прилагательного  "недопустимые".

Answer (score 1):

Слова на МЫЙ в большинстве случаев пишутся слитно. Практически возможны только две формы с раздельным написанием:усиление отрицания  (никому не ведомый) и раздельное написание причастия при наличии слова в Т.п. (не замечаемый людьми герой), причем причастие должно быть образовано от переходного глагола несовершенного вида. Кроме того, в обоих случаях  слово должно употребляться без НЕ (никем непобедимый народ, невыразимые словами чувство).

Так как  "допустить" является глаголом совершенного вида, то причастия из него не получится. Можно при желании образовать усилительную конструкцию: ни в коей мере не допустимо. Все остальные варианты будут писаться только слитно: это недопустимо, такие поступки недопустимы, поступать так совершенно недопустимо и всё прочее недопустимое.

Comment: "Так как "допустить" является глаголом совершенного вида...".
Здесь вы имеете в виду, что от него нельзя образовать причастия на -мый?

Comment: Страдательные причастия настоящего времени образуются от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида. Поэтому слово  "допустимый" всегда является прилагательным, хотя при его образовании используется суффикс причастия. Это информация чисто по форме слова. Что касается содержания, то оно здесь  интереснее. Причастие должно обозначать признак по действию, то есть признак, отнесенный ко времени. Например, "видимый мною предмет" - здесь "видимый" при наличии зависимого слова в Т.п. является причастием, так как обозначает действие производителя, реально протекающее во времени.

Answer (score 0):

Различается написание не с отглагольными прилагательными на -мый и с причастиями на -мый. Первые подчиняются правилам написания не с прилагательными, вторые – с причастиями.

К прилагательным относятся слова, образованные от непереходных глаголов: невредимый, невысыхаемый, независимый, незначимый или от глаголов совершенного вида (причастия на -мый от глаголов совершенного вида не образуются): невыполнимый (от выполнить – сов. в.), неистощимый (истощить), неисчислимый (исчислить). Эти и подобные им слова подчиняются всем изложенным правилам написания не с прилагательными: независимые страны, независимое от внешних условий поведение, совершенно независимый характер, страны экономически независимы, эти страны независимее других. Но, согласно правилам написания не с прилагательными при наличии отрицательных местоимений и наречий, а также частиц далеко, отнюдь, не с прилагательными на -мый пишется раздельно: ни от чего не зависимый результат, отнюдь не зависимый взгляд на вещи.

Слова на -мый, образованные от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида, в зависимости от контекста могут быть и страдательными причастиями, и прилагательными. Причастиями такие слова являются при наличии пояснительного слова в творительном падеже (творительного действующего лица или творительного орудия). При других формах пояснительных слов или без пояснительных слов они переходят в прилагательные и, следовательно, подчиняются общим для прилагательных правилам написания частицы не (теряют значение страдательности, значение времени и приобретают качественное значение); ср.: невидимые слезы, невидимые миру слезы, никому не видимые слезы (прилагательное), не видимые мною слезы (причастие).

Исключения: слова, которые без не не употребляются: никем непобедимая страна, ни для кого непостижимый случай, ни при каких условиях неповторимый опыт.